# Disable a drop down menu if a certain value is selected upon editing form

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, edit

I want to disable the drop down menu when a user edits a form and the selected value of drop down menu is `1`.

This is what I currently have: when a user clicks `submit`, it will check if the selected value is `1`, then, it will pop up an alert box.

What I wish to do is to pop up the alert box and disable the drop down menu.

The drop down menu is an echoed value:

```
< td >< ?php echo $this->item->statusList;?>< /td >
```

Thank you in advance!

```
else if (document.getElementById('status')[document.getElementById('status').selectedIndex].value == 1) 
{
    document.getElementById('status').focus();
    alert("<?php echo JText::_('This cannot be modified because it is 1', true); ?>");
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to process the request having the `<option>` 1 in your `select` then why not rendering at all this option? Unless you are talking about two different `select`

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideselect(value)
{
if(value ==1)
{
document.getElementById('status').disabled=true;
}
}
</script>

<select name='test' onchange='hideselect(this.value)';>
<option value='1'>one</option>
<option value='2'>two</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for ur solution but the drop down menu is a generated via php < td >< ?php echo $this->item->statusList;?>< /td >

Answer (score 0):

Given the index of the option you wish to disable, you can do the following:

```
document.getElementById('status')[1].disabled = true;
```

(Index of 1 used for example.)